# Virtual host domains other than .local not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, wamp, virtual-host

I have virtual host `example.dev` in my WAMP. I was able to run it in Chrome and Firefox by browsing `http://example.dev`.

In a couple days back, I can no longer run it in Chrome, it keeps redirecting to `https://example.dev`. It seems looking for actual domain on web. I can still browse it in Firefox. When I created a new virtual host `example.local`, I can run `http://example.local` in both Chrome and Firefox. I'm not sure what changes/settings made Chrome unable to browse the virtual host using `.dev` (same for `.app`).

I want `.dev` vhost because Google Calendar API allows only `.dev` for redirect URIs configuration that is used to test my project calendar integration.

Comment: ['da reg' thinks this happened over a month ago](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/11/29/google_dev_network/) -- was your Chrome out of date?

Comment: Yeah I about to say without a background in Chrome dev apps that this is related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security which simply means your app needs to provide a https version.

Comment: I feel that this Register article is biased. It’s been said again and again for years that you *must not* use arbitrary TLDs for internal purposes. And yet every time a new gTLD is registered, someone comes crying. The Register even fails to mention that `.local` also *must not* be used for anything but Multicast DNS.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue:

- Debian 9
- Firefox Developer edition
- VirtualHost `snowscootworld.dev`
- File `/etc/hosts` --> `127.0.1.1 snowscootworld.dev`

Using the mentioned configuration it worked under Firefox ESR but not with Firefox Developer. FF Developer browser was automatically redirecting all `http://snowscootworld.dev` request to `https://snowscootworld.dev` as mentioned in the question. I tried also to change to `.local` extensions as suggested but nothing changed.

At the end I decided to approach the problem from the beginning. I read the article about TLDs on WikiPedia (in conclusion it's better to use `.test` extension for local development) and another about localhost addressing (use `127.0.0.1`, `127.0.1.1` is a Debian/Ubuntu standard for mapping the ip of your host_name in case that you have no network).

So, the right configuration that works under all browsers is:

- VirtualHost `snowscootworld.test`
- File `/etc/hosts` --> `127.0.0.1 snowscootworld.test`

HTH

Comment: Unfortunately, we can only set `.dev` in google developer console for calendar API redirect URI. `.test`, `.local`, etc. can't be set. I described it in my question last paragraph.

Comment: .dev didn't work with any browsers on your system? I was forced to change the domain name because t was not working under FF Developer but was working with Firefox normal version.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work FF anymore. It was working before.

Comment: But it doesn't matter anymore since I can set http://localhost/myproject in google console instead of virtual host.

Comment: Ok, good to know!